# Solr Join query to combine two queries

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

My first Solr query is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=id:idval
```

Using the result(only 1 result is returned) I get from this query, I take the "latlon" field value(let's call it **latlonval** from the result and pass it in to the following query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=*:*&fq={!geofilt pt=latlonval sfield=latlon d=50}
```

Using two queries is taking too much time to process. Is there anyway to combine these two queries into a single query? Probably using joins. If so, please show me how.

Comment: Which part of those queries are taking too much time? My guess is that your second query is _really_ expensive, and the first one should complete (it's a single index lookup after all) in a ms or less. My guess is that your second query should probably be optimized (using a different field type, different settings (docvalues), etc.) - turn off caching if the coordinates used are fairly unique.

Comment: @MatsLindh I want to combine those queries into a single query. A nested query of some sort. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: My point is that combining them might not be the easiest solution, and will probably not make things go much faster - if the last query is what consumes 99.99% of your time, then removing the one roundtrip won't do much in any direction.

Comment: @MatsLindh I felt making a single query is better than making two different queries.